# batch code to run ccleaner

Tags: batch-file

How do I start CCleaner with batch commmand. I am using this.

```
start /d /B "c:\windows\system32" ccleaner.exe
```

But it only starts ccleaner doesn't start the cleaning.

Comment: Your parameters to `start` are incorrect. It should be `start /B /d "C:\Windows\System32" ccleaner.exe`. The `/d` specifies that you're providing a path, and the next thing after it should be that path. As you have it written now, it's trying to use `/B` as the path name, and clearly that path doesn't exist. (You can also use `start /d "C:\Windows\System32" /B ccleaner.exe` - the importance is that the path needs to immediately follow the /d parameter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CCleaner.exe /AUTO
```

You will need to CD to the CCleaner.exe directory first or include the path to CCleaner.exe (e.g., "C:\Program Files\Piriform\CCleaner.exe").

See https://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters

"CCleaner runs silently and automatically, using the **current set of saved options** to clean the PC. CCleaner then exits."

Comment: I tried this code on windows server r2012 and it didn't work. How can I make it work on that OS ?

Comment: Did you start the script or command prompt in administrative mode?